# Why religious activities aren't suggested during absence of Venus?

Tags: belief, culture

In most of places where Hindu religion is believed, Most of the religious activities are not suggested during period of absence of Venus. Can anyone describe reason behind this ?

Comment: this is a question about astrology, not about the Hindu religion.

Comment: This is believed in Hindu religion so I've asked

Comment: what is the source of your belief?

Comment: why are you asking about source of belief ? does belief has source seriously ?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Astrology questions are on topic. And Astrology is part of Hindu Religion.

Comment: 'most places where Hindu religion is practiced' is anecdotal evidence, it is not scriptural. who's belief? who told you? If no scriptural source, then its not religious, its popular custom or superstition or astrological.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Astrology is an ancient Indian science, but it is not vedic.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Jyotishya is one of the six limbs of Vedas (Vedangas). It is believed to have connection with Vedas. And moreover, Astrology has Hindu Gods which makes it a proper question for this site.

Comment: There are a lot of religious belief regarding Sun Moon Earth Venus Mars. So, we can't relate them with Hindu religion ?

Comment: Can you clarify about your question? What is "absence of Venus" and what are those "places"? It helps the users when the question is clear. You can modify your question by clicking edit option. use @ before username to reply to a specific user.

Comment: The duration in which Venus is not seen from earth at night

Comment: @SreeCharan Absence of Venus is Shukra asta period in which no auspicious rituals like marriage gruha pravesha is not done.

Comment: @Yogi You have said what I actually want to say

Comment: @TheDestroyer I am willing to change my opinion if you can give a vedic reference for the astrology. 'Believed to have connections' is imprecise and indeterminate. No one can give a vedic reference because there are none. Just one!